# What does empty square brackets represent as a variable value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm wondering what do those empty square brackets do in those two variables (invited, rsvps) in the code below.

```
Parties.insert({
  _id: id,
  owner: this.userId,
  x: options.x,
  y: options.y,
  title: options.title,
  description: options.description,
  public: !! options.public,
  invited: [],
  rsvps: [],
  likes: 0,
});
```

Comment: An empty array/collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]` is shorthand for `new Array()`. Its often prevert above `new Array()` because its more lightweight for the JavaScript engine.

With `new Array()` the engine has to go up the scope chain to find the constructor. And this constructor could have been overwritten or manipulated.

Comment: thanks for answering my question! It was very helpful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

[] are used to define an array. So that the variable can store multiple objects in one object.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is an empty array that has no value.