# Using empty Brackets when accessing flow object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, flowtype

Reading through some code here: ([redux organization](http://jaysoo.ca/2016/02/28/organizing-redux-application/)) and noticed the following code.

```
// todos/model.js
export type Todo = {
  id?: number;
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
};

// This is the model of our module state (e.g. return type of the reducer)
export type State = Todo[];
```

This looks like [Flow](https://flowtype.org/docs/) code and most of it makes sense. But I'm a little confused what the of the **empty brackets on Todo[]** mean.

Typically in js you use empty brackets to assign an empty array. Though i've never seen it used like this. Is this a Flow feature? Couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does empty square brackets represent as a variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878786/what-does-empty-square-brackets-represent-as-a-variable-value-in-javascript)

Comment: This is Flowtype-annotated code, none of this is ES6. Are you wondering specifically about the `[]`, because it seems more likely that you don't know what Flowtype is.

Comment: You wondered about that but not about `type` or `?` ?

Comment: Yeah never heard of flow until now, so good to know. In this specific case I'm wondering specifically what the empty brackets are doing. As I can find what they are doing based on the flow docs.

Comment: It's an alternative syntax for declaring Array types. I believe they copied that syntax from TypeScript to be compatible, but the preferred way to write that would be `Array<Todo>`. The syntax shows up in Flow's Quick Reference for Arrays: https://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html#arrays

Answer (score 2):

It means that `State` is array of Todo objects.

For example `number[]` is array of numbers.

[Array types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

It's an alternative syntax for declaring Array types in Flow. It may have been copied from [TypeScript's Array syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) to be compatible, but the preferred way to write that in Flow annotations would be the following:

```
export type State = Array<Todo>;
```

The bracket syntax shows up in Flow's Quick Reference for Arrays: https://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html#arrays. Here's the excerpt:

```
let array: number[] = [1, 2, 3.14, 42];
```